# Parallel Processing in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to run my 2(two) SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition as if one server. If one server is too busy, system should direct the requests to other server.
How can I do this? Thanks..

Comment: Sounds like you want it to work as an Active/Active cluster - I'm not sure it supports that, but the place to ask would be [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as you want, SQL Server does not support 'load balancing'. Active/Active clusters are about two *different* clusters being active on the same hosts(s).

You can scale out *reads* using technologies like [AlwaysOn](http://rusanu.com/2010/11/11/alwayson-high-availability-and-reads-scale-out/), you can scale out writes *asynchronously* (with eventual consistency) using [sharding data in the application layer](http://rusanu.com/2011/06/01/scale-out-sql-server-by-using-reliable-messaging/), [SQL Azure Federations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh597452.aspx), [Merge Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746%28v=sql.105%29) or [Updateable Subscriptions with Transactional Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151718.aspx) (now deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

Look into SQL server service broker. This is an asynchronous messaging system in SQL server.
There is a way to read from a queue using a stored procedure running in multiple processes